# min-h-screen Tailwind CSS Class Didn't Cover the Width of Screen

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container min-h-screen bg-[url('images/Image.png')] bg-center bg-cover px-28 py-5">
        <nav class="flex items-center">
            <img src="images/logo.png" >
            <ul class="flex-1 text-center">
                <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="home.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="about.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">About</a></li>
                <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="features.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Features</a></li>
                <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="contact.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/cart.png">
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code above didn't work that I expected. I'm beginner in tailwind but I follow video in Youtube that it works with him and didn't work with me.

Why Div Element can't cover the width of browser and some phones on both height and width. Body still appear! I need some help...

I have tried h-full w-full h-screen w-screen but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `container` class. [As per the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container):

> The `container` class sets the `max-width` of an element to match the `min-width` of the current breakpoint.

This `max-width` behavior would be what is preventing the top-level `<div>` element from covering the width of the viewport.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="min-h-screen bg-[url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080)] bg-center bg-cover px-28 py-5">
    <nav class="flex items-center">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/32/32">
        <ul class="flex-1 text-center">
            <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="home.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Home</a></li>
            <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="about.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">About</a></li>
            <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="features.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Features</a></li>
            <li class="list-none inline-block px-5"><a href="contact.html" class="no-underline text-white px-2">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/32/32?">
    </nav>
</div>
```